# Accessing Digital Ocean server gives an error message while you SSH

Tags: ssh

I have changed droplet SSH password. Now when I try to SSH, It gives me warning.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  In order to help we really need more information - like the error message you are getting - in order to help.  Other things like the OS and variant are useful to.   Also, how you changed the SSH password on it?  (My wild guess is you did something which caused the host key to regenerate, and you need to remove the offending host key from your SSH client)

Comment: I ve changed SSH password using DO console. I'm using Ubuntu and can access same droplet in another computer via SSH . But my laptop also has Ubuntu

Comment: I dont know what DO console is but what is the warning message ?

Comment: When You login to digital ocean server, There is a button "change root password."I used that. Warning message is "Remote host identification has changed.""Add correct host key."  Is host key is Server IP address pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Without understanding the Digital Ocean specifics) the warning is a common one, and is as per my guess.

The SSH server has its own key (which includes the private key). The server provides  the associated public key to you the first time you connect to it - which your ssh client stores. Future SSH attempts will use this to check you ate speaking to the same server.you initially spoke to to thwart man-in-the-middle attacks.

When the servers host key changes (which it would.not do if the root password changed, but would do it the droplet was recreated - which may be related to how DO is changing it) you gret a warning as described by you.

The solution is to remove your stored host key for that system. (In Unixy versions of SSH this is stored in an authorised_keys file, and you can  find and remove the offending line. There are other ways.as well dependong on your SSH client.)

Note that none of this has to do with IPs - the IP address.of the server can change without modifying this (host) key.

Comment: Thank You Very much for your prompt reply.